# How to understand when the system use autocomplete in textView in Swift

Tags: swift, autocomplete, textview, ios10

I have TextView and enabled text suggestions. How can I understand when user is writing part of the word and when press Space/Return the system autocomplete the word?

My problem is that I want to change the Font and go to new line when the user press Font changing button on the screen. Now when the button is clicked, the system add the line, the new font, but after that add his autocompletion and override my added line and change my Selected Range.

At the end the cursor is on previous line between the letters of the added autocompleted word and when start typing it is with my new added Font.

P.S.

> textView.autocorrectionType = .no

is not working, because the system knows it wants to change the word. The only found solution is

> resignFirstResponder()
>
> beginFirstResponder()

in my method. This will make the autocomplete first and after that continue with my method. And yeah, because I make both of them there is no moving keyboard(hide, show), but I want to find better solution

Comment: why don't you turn off the autocorrection everytime you are selecting a font? And then turning it on when the font is selected and the editing has begun. 
`textView.autocorrectionType = .no`

Comment: I already tried this. It's not working.